# Ordering of inherited types in memory

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, c++14

Can I assume the memory locations of a class's members are in the order they appear in it's definition no matter what?

```
struct Color {
    uint8 r, g, b;
};
struct Vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Object : public Color, Vec3 {
    uint32 data;
}object;
```

In other words, would `object.r` always be before `object.x` which itself would always be before `object.data`?

Or to be more specific, will the following code always hold true?

```
assert( offsetof(Object, b)    ==  offsetof(Color, b) );
assert( offsetof(Object, z)    ==  sizeof(Color) + offsetof(Vec3, z) );
assert( offsetof(Object, data) ==  sizeof(Color) + sizeof(Vec3) );
```

Comment: Even if they are, what do you expect to be able to use this knowledge for?

Comment: @walnut - evil.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148075/order-of-memory-allocation-in-c

Comment: want to slice a wad of memory up a certain way, and something that looks like "Object" is used as a lazy interface, where the inherited types are sections I want to slice out conditionally

Comment: If you do what you want by lying to the compiler, you may find you have to compile your code with optimizations turned off.  On the other hand, if you do what you don't want to do, and do it the verbose and explicit way, it is likely the compiler can optimize the code to be as efficient as the way you wanted to do behind the compiler's back.

Comment: @walnut - ah, yeah I messed that up, I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `Object` is not standard-layout, because its (direct and indirect) non-static data members are not all declared in the same class.

Therefore pretty much the only guarantee you have is that members declared in the same class and with same access specifier are ordered according to their declaration order:

```
r < g < b
x < y < z
```

and that the ordering of sub-objects of sub-objects is consistent, i.e. that if `data < r` also `data < b` and so on.

(The names are supposed to represent addresses here.)

I don't think there are any other guarantees by the C++ standard, but the ABI your platform is using will specify this in more detail.

By the way, since the class isn't standard-layout, `offsetof` has undefined behavior in C++14 (and is only conditionally-supported since C++17).

The assertions need not be satisfied, even if the ordering requirements were fulfilled, because there can be padding between subobjects.

Comment: Would it be strictly ordered if the inherited members were not inherited, but instead were declared as normal members like `class Object{Color color; Vec3 vec; uint32 data};`?

Comment: @AnneQuinn Yes, I guess it would, but it still doesn't guarantee that the assertions are true, because there can be padding in the structure.